# Creating a custom EPiServer workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, episerver, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2

I've been tasked with creating an EPiServer workflow in version 6 R2. The workflow we require needs the following steps:

- When a page is created in any language an approval is sent (to users or groups)
- Once the page is approved, a notification is sent to the relevant people notifying them that they must create a page in another required language - for example if a page is created and approved in English a notification would be sent to the relevant people saying it must also be created in French.
- Once each of the other language pages are created they too must be approved.
- Once ALL of the pages in each of the required languages have been created they are all published.

I realise this is a pretty open ended question, but can anyone give any guidance on this, has anyone done anything similar?

Also, I read that EPiServer used the .NET 3.5 framework whereas .NET 4 WWF had a major overhaul. http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=49261

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
higgsy

Answer (score 1):

While EPiServer 6 supports .net 4, it's not actually built against 4.0, so I believe you're restricted to using the .NET 3.5 WF features.

The SDK has a pretty comprehensive guide to creating custom workflows. Take a look here: [Developers Guide > Advanced Features > Workflows](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6.1/index.aspx)